# What purpose has this tiny clip on my power cable?

Tags: laptop, power-supply

With the Asus N550J I bought, I received an adapter which has a tiny clip attached to it:

[image]

As it seems, the exact same cable fits perfectly in that clip, as shown below:

[image]

On [this page](http://lifehacker.com/5791354/get-better-control-over-your-macbooks-power-cord-with-its-built-in-wrapping-clip) some usages are shown, but I'm not convinced that these are why they're present. The second usage for example shows you how you can use the clip for some 'stress lessening', but I don't see how this would work, as the clip is quite rigid.

What is the purpose of these clips?

Comment: Just a WAG. If you are like my wife, you are constantly tripping over the cord. By clipping it with a loop like in the picture, instead of yanking it out of the computer, you will just pull it out of the clip.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what the brick end of the power cord looks like, but it's for when you wrap the cord up to travel with it.  The clip binds the end to the rest of the cable to keep it tight.

I think Apple basically made this trendy.  Macs have a pair of ears on the brick that you wrap the cable around.  Then the end clips to the rest of the cable for a nice, tight bundle that you can throw into your bag.

That article where the person clipped it to the screen... I never would've thought of that.  Not what it's for but interesting.

[image]

Comment: Ah, that kind of makes sense. The brick is just a brick, without the 'ears' Apple supplies.

Comment: After trying it out, it's a perfect solution for tyding up your cable! [This is the result](http://i.stack.imgur.com/VTEPE.jpg). Thanks!