# Google Chrome is adding a slash to my searches

Tags: google-chrome, search

In google chrome (version 39.0.2138.3) when I enter a special text in the omnibar at the top it always suggests to add a '/' symbol.

[image: screenshot of the problem]
.

Now I cannot press enter to search as I usually would because then it will use "c/# code..."

It's not only that suggestion doesn't make any sense; the main problem is that chrome won't even search for the (incorrect) string. It just displays: ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED because it interprets the slash as a hostname or something.

I tried to reinstall google chrome but the problem didn't go away. It's still suggesting "unsearchable" suggestions.

What causes this? What can I do so I don't have to do tricks like clicking into the bar again so the suggestions disappear...

Comment: What happens if you type `"c#"` (i.e., type `c#` in quotes)?

Comment: That works as intended and doesn't try to be 'helpful', but it will use googles "exact match" search. But a nice find is that I can type just one quote at the beginning (no closing ") and it works as intended!

Comment: I have this same issue, does this come from a recent chrome update? I'm sure I did not used to experience this. It's extremely irritating

Comment: @Dan: Very recent behavior for me as well, noticed it for the first  time maybe 4 days ago or so.

Comment: @Cory I reported it as an issue to Chrome asking them to make an exception if this is indeed a new feature. Perhaps you should too. Under the chrome menu -> Help -> Report Issue

Comment: @Dan: I have submitted my feedback. Strange this about this is if you search initially, let it add the slash, then manually remove the slash it added and hit enter, it will submit the search unmangled as expected. At least, that's what I'm observing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's doing this because having a `#` in the URL usually means to link to a specific anchor on a page, because it is reading what you entered as a URL. For example the url:

```
http://superuser.com/questions/806272/.../806274#806274
```

Means link to the anchor name `#806274`. Chrome is trying to be helpful by adding in a slash to your URL because it thinks you may have missed it.

As far as I know there is no way to disable this action, other similar features can be found in the "privacy" portion of your settings, but none of them seem to have any affect. If you're so inclined, you can file an [issue with Chromium](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/list) to specify that this should not be the default behaviour (check to see if the issue exists on Chromium before filing the issue report though).

It looks like there was an issue opened recently in the Chromium issues list [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=414678&q=C%23&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified), and there is a similar ongoing issue [here](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6848&q=C%23&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) for those who want to keep track.

Comment: looks like this will be fixed for Chrome 40. https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=409845#c19

Answer (score 0):

I found that you can get around this problem by ending your search with c# instead of beginning with it. As a side note I believe that this was a bug that was fixed late last year (2014)