# Chrome doesn't search when hitting enter for a lot of words, in stead adds "/"

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, search

I've seen some people experiencing this problem when searching for things like "C#" (ref: [Google Chrome is adding a slash to my searches](https://superuser.com/questions/806282/google-chrome-is-adding-a-slash-to-my-searches) ). However, for me, Chrome is doing this randomly at all time. With some words, it starts searching, with others, it just adds a / at the end and gives a "page not available" error.

My problem is best explained by this video:
https://youtu.be/1DXPLCUYLGM

I *never* used to have this problem. It started yesterday. And it's SUPER RANDOM as well, because just now, I typed "translate" and it would search for "translate", and 1 minute later, I typed "translate" again, and it added a / and gave the error page...

I have no idea what's going on, but it's super annoying, because I'm used to just typing one word and hitting enter to get to the page that I'm looking for.

The problem seems to be very very inconsistent. One moment it will go search for what I'm looking for, the next it won't.

I figured out that you can tell when it's going to work, because then the top suggestion is "Search Google For": 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/uDGFt.png

as opposed to when it's giving the error page, and the top suggestion is just what I entered in the address bar:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/CEuCB.png

(hitting enter in the 2nd example gives an error page, because it's not performing a search)

WHY does it sometimes have "Search Google For" as top suggestion, and the NEXT time it doesn't, with the *SAME* word entered...

I have cleared my browsing history, didn't help.

Hope you have any ideas or suggestions.
As I said, this only started happening since like yesterday... 
I haven't made any changes to my computer whatsoever. Also didn't update Chrome or anything...

Cheers!

EDIT: I'm on Windows 7, Chrome 50.0.2661.94 m

EDIT2: Now I'm on Chrome 50.0.2661.102 m, the problem still persists...